# After use mod_proxy_fcgi, the page is shown but the network status is 404

Tags: php, apache

When I use php7 for Apache in Windows, I try to use mod_proxy_fcgi.
So I use mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi and set that thing in httpd.conf:

```
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/" enablereuse=on max=10>
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    # Note: The only part that varies is /path/to/app.sock
    SetHandler  "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
</FilesMatch>
```

And I also set the doc_root="E:/AMP/www" in php.ini

After I start apache and php-cgi in that way:

```
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c php.ini
```

The page is show on the browser but status code is 404 in the network's panel of F12

Is there anything I missed ?